# How to Concatenate Numbers and Strings to Format Numbers in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ActualWeightDIMS]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @ActualWeight int,
    @Actual_Dims_Lenght int,
    @Actual_Dims_Width int,
    @Actual_Dims_Height int
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ActualWeightDIMS varchar(50);
--Actual Weight
     IF (@ActualWeight is not null) 
          SET @ActualWeightDIMS = @ActualWeight;
--Actual DIMS
     IF (@Actual_Dims_Lenght is not null) AND 
          (@Actual_Dims_Width is not null) AND (@Actual_Dims_Height is not null)
          SET @ActualWeightDIMS= @Actual_Dims_Lenght + 'x' + @Actual_Dims_Width + 'x' + @Actual_Dims_Height;


     RETURN(@ActualWeightDIMS);

END
```

but when i tried to use it, i got the following error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'x' to data type int." when i use the following select statement

```
select 
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.ID_Number [ID_Number],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.Submit_Date [Submit_Date],
 BA_Category.Category [category],
 BA_Type_Of_Request.Request [Type_Of_Request],
 dbo.ActualWeightDIMS(BA_Adjustment_Detail.ActualWeight,BA_Adjustment_Detail.Actual_Dims_Lenght,BA_Adjustment_Detail.Actual_Dims_Width,BA_Adjustment_Detail.Actual_Dims_Height) [Actual Weight/DIMS],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.Notes [Notes],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.UPSCustomerNo [UPSNo],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.TrackingNo [AirbillNo],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.StoreNo [StoreNo],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.Download_Date [Download_Date],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.Shipment_Date[ShipmentDate],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.FranchiseNo [FranchiseNo],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.CustomerNo [CustomerNo],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.BillTo [BillTo],
 BA_Adjustment_Detail.Adjustment_Amount_Requested [Adjustment_Amount_Requested]
from BA_Adjustment_Detail
inner join BA_Category 
on BA_Category.ID = BA_Adjustment_Detail.CategoryID
inner join BA_Type_Of_Request
on BA_Type_Of_Request.ID = BA_Adjustment_Detail.TypeOfRequestID
```

What I want to do is if the ActualWeight is not null then return the ActualWeight for the "Actual Weight/DIMS" or else use the Actual_Dims_Lenght, Width and Height.

If it is DIMS then i want to format the output to be LenghtxWidhtxHeight (15x10x4). The ActualWeight, Adcutal_Dims_Lenght, Width and Height are all int (integer) value but the output for "Actual Weight/DIMS" should be varchar(50).

Where am i getting it wrong?

thank

edit: The user can only pick either Weight or DIMS on ASP.net page and if user selected DIMS then they must supply Length, Width and Height. Else it will throw error on the ASP.net page. Should i worry about it on the sql side?

Comment: when you try to concatenate varchar or Nvarchar with other Data type it may cause the error try to convert data types  `@Actual_Dims_Lenght,@Actual_Dims_Width,@Actual_Dims_Height` using `Cast or Convert built in functions`

Answer (score 226, accepted):

A couple of quick notes:

- It's "length" not "lenght"
- Table aliases in your query would probably make it a lot more readable

Now onto the problem...

You need to explicitly convert your parameters to VARCHAR before trying to concatenate them. When SQL Server sees @my_int + 'X' it thinks you're trying to add the number "X" to @my_int and it can't do that. Instead try:

```
SET @ActualWeightDIMS =
     CAST(@Actual_Dims_Lenght AS VARCHAR(16)) + 'x' +
     CAST(@Actual_Dims_Width  AS VARCHAR(16)) + 'x' +
     CAST(@Actual_Dims_Height  AS VARCHAR(16))
```

Comment: You should always specify the length of a varchar: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Thanks. A bit late, but I've added the length parameters.

Answer (score 76):

If you are using **SQL Server 2012+** you can use [**CONCAT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh231515.aspx) function in which we don't have to do any explicit conversion

```
SET @ActualWeightDIMS = Concat(@Actual_Dims_Lenght, 'x', @Actual_Dims_Width, 'x' 
                        , @Actual_Dims_Height)
```

Comment: I have come across some claims that `CONCAT()` performs faster than `CAST()`.  Reliable sources of performance studies would be useful.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it was measurable in a benchmark, but I would be very surprised if it made any impact in normal queries. You'd have to have an enormous number of casts to drown out the normal operating time.

Answer (score 10):

Change this:

```
SET @ActualWeightDIMS= @Actual_Dims_Lenght + 'x' + 
    @Actual_Dims_Width + 'x' + @Actual_Dims_Height;
```

To this:

```
SET @ActualWeightDIMS= CAST(@Actual_Dims_Lenght as varchar(3)) + 'x' + 
    CAST(@Actual_Dims_Width as varchar(3)) + 'x' + 
    CAST(@Actual_Dims_Height as varchar(3));
```

Change this:

```
SET @ActualWeightDIMS = @ActualWeight;
```

To this:

```
SET @ActualWeightDIMS = CAST(@ActualWeight as varchar(50));
```

You need to use CAST.  Learn all about CAST and CONVERT [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), because data types are important!

Answer (score 8):

```
select 'abcd' + ltrim(str(1)) + ltrim(str(2))
```

Comment: I don't understand how this addresses the question.

Answer (score 4):

Cast the integers to varchar first!

Comment: Exactly. The string 'x' completely hammers the pointless int decls; there is no arithmetic in the UDF.

Answer (score 4):

You must cast your integers as string when trying to concatenate them into a varchar.

i.e.

```
 SELECT  @ActualWeightDIMS = CAST(@Actual_Dims_Lenght AS varchar(10)) 
                              + 'x' + 
                             CAST(@Actual_Dims_Width as varchar(10)) 
                             + 'x' + CAST(@Actual_Dims_Height as varchar(10));
```

In SQL Server 2008, you can use the [`STR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function:

```
   SELECT  @ActualWeightDIMS = STR(@Actual_Dims_Lenght) 
                              + 'x' + STR(@Actual_Dims_Width) 
                              + 'x' + STR(@Actual_Dims_Height);
```

Comment: The STR function by default pads the number to 10 characters so it adds loads of spaces. e.g. `STR(1)` gives me 9 spaces followed by `1`.  `CAST` actually works better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to CAST your numeric data to strings before you do string concatenation, so for example use `CAST(@Actual_Dims_Lenght AS VARCHAR)` instead of just `@Actual_Dims_Lenght`, &c.

Answer (score 2):

I was tried the below query it's works for me exactly

```
 with cte as(

   select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by repairid) as'RN', [RepairProductId] from [Ws_RepairList]
  )
  update CTE set [RepairProductId]= ISNULL([RepairProductId]+convert(nvarchar(10),RN),0) from cte
```

Answer (score 2):

There are chances that you might end up with Scientific Number when you convert Integer to Str... safer way is

`SET @ActualWeightDIMS = STR(@Actual_Dims_Width); OR
Select STR(@Actual_Dims_Width) + str(@Actual_Dims_Width)`

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the ints to varchar, before adding them to a string:

```
SET @ActualWeightDIMS = cast(@Actual_Dims_Lenght as varchar(8)) + 
   'x' + cast(@Actual_Dims_Width as varchar(8)) + 
   'x' + cast(@Actual_Dims_Height as varhcar(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

set @values=concat(string,number,string)