# Combine varchar column with int column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two columns in a SQL table, `fooId` (int) and `fooName` (varchar).

Is there a way to select them both as one column with a space between them?

```
select fooId + ' ' + fooName as fooEntity
from mytable
```

They're different types so I'm getting an error.

This field will be databound directly in a control in the web app.

SQL Server 2008

(I'm a bit of a sql beginner)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Concatenate Numbers and Strings to Format Numbers in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951320/how-to-concatenate-numbers-and-strings-to-format-numbers-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

String concatenation is different between databases, so it helps to know which database because you need to know:

1. The concatenation method/operator
2. If the database handles implicit data type conversion

**SQL Server** doesn't do implicit conversion of numeric into string values:

```
SELECT CAST(fooid AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + fooname
```

...so you need to use [CAST (or CONVERT)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to explicitly change the data type to a text based data type.

For **Oracle & PostgreSQL**, use the double pipe to concatenate strings:

```
SELECT fooid || ' ' || fooname
```

For **MySQL**, you can use the [CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT CONCAT(fooid, ' ', fooname)
```

Comment: Ah, this one is much more complete than my answer.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Convert( foold, SQL_CHAR ) + ' ' + fooName FROM mytable
```

or

```
SELECT Cast( foold AS SQL_CHAR(10) ) + ' ' + fooName FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's standard SQL, but PostgreSQL uses the `||` operator for string concatenation. `+` means numerical addition.

Answer (score 0):

I use this query in MS SQL

```
SELECT varcharColumn + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), intColumn) AS foo
```

Assuming varcharColumn is null

```
SELECT ISNULL(varcharColumn, '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), intColumn) AS foo
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah that should be OK, as long as the bound field is a string.

Whats the error you getting?

Comment: This could have been a comment!