# Concatenate a Varchar and int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to Concatenate a `Varchar` and `int`  in T-SQL , !

Comment: As in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150943/combine-varchar-column-with-int-column?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
SELECT ('VarValue' + CAST(32 AS VARCHAR))
```

Comment: It's a best practice to declare VARCHAR variables / parameters with a length.  See for example: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 8):

```
varcharName + cast(intName as varchar) as full_name
```

Should do it