# In sql sever, building dynamic sql with integer variables

Tags: sql

I'm building this dynamic sql but getting an error when executing it.

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT 
                    DDoSAttacksId,
                    AttackId,
                    TargetIP,
                    PeakBPS, 
                    DateStarted                                                                
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateStarted Desc) AS Row,
                    DDoSAttacksId                                 AS DDoSAttacksId,
                    AttackId                                      AS AttackId,
                    TargetIP                                      As TargetIP,
                    CONCAT(PeakBPS / 1000000000,' Gbps')        As PeakBPS,
                    DateStarted                                   AS DateStarted
                FROM
                    DDosAttacks
                WHERE TargetIP IN ('108.61.51.101', '206.221.181.5')) AS DDosAttacksRows
            WHERE
                (Row between (' to data type int.
```

Note: It plugs in the IPAddress just fine, but not the integer values.

```
set quoted_identifier off

declare @sql              nvarchar(4000),
        @PageNumber       int,
        @PageSize         int,
        @IPAddressList   varchar(100)

Select @IPAddressList = "'108.61.51.101', '206.221.181.5'"

select @sql= 'SELECT 
                DDoSAttacksId,
                AttackId,
                TargetIP,
                PeakBPS, 
                DateStarted                                                                
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateStarted Desc) AS Row,
                DDoSAttacksId                                 AS DDoSAttacksId,
                AttackId                                      AS AttackId,
                TargetIP                                      As TargetIP,
                CONCAT(PeakBPS / 1000000000,'' Gbps'')        As PeakBPS,
                DateStarted                                   AS DateStarted
            FROM
                DDosAttacks
            WHERE TargetIP IN ('+@IPAddressList+')) AS DDosAttacksRows
        WHERE
            (Row between ('+@PageNumber+' * ('+@PageSize+' - '+@PageSize+')) AND ('+@PageNumber+' * ('+@PageSize+' - 1)))';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

I can hard code numbers in their place it and executes fine....for example (Row between (1 * (20 - 20)) AND (1 * (20 - 1)))';

Comment: It appears you are trying to construct a `NVARCHAR` string by concatenating type `int` (ie, `@PageNumber` in the `(Row between (' + @PageNumber +` line) which is invalid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Concatenate Numbers and Strings to Format Numbers in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951320/how-to-concatenate-numbers-and-strings-to-format-numbers-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like:

```
'(Row between ('+ cast(@PageNumber as varchar(255)) +' * ('+cast(@PageSizeas varchar(255)) +' - '+cast(@PageSize as varchar(255))+')) AND ('+cast(@PageNumber as varchar(255))+' * ('+cast(@PageSize as varchar(255))+' - 1)))';
```

Updated my answer to provided a length of the casted varchar's due to KM response below. thank you KM for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks it worked.. to everyone who responded similarly...thanks.

Comment: It is a worst practice to not specify a length to your char/varchar.  You will eventually get burned when your data is truncated because the default is smaller than the resulting string.

Comment: @KM With regards to your comment, wouldn't the system allocate the `MAX` length to the `VARCHAR` when a length is omitted within a `CAST`?

Comment: @user3020047 In an effort to help the community, you should mark answers as accepted as often as you can. It helps to quickly identify a solution to a problem that other users may be experiencing.

Comment: @Anthony Forloney, **no SQL Server WILL NOT default varchar to max**.  When declaring a variable like `DECLARE @x varchar` it will default to `varchar(1)`.  When using an in-line conversion like in the answer, it will default to `varchar(30)`.  SQL Server can't read your mind, or understand your needs, so always select a data type and length appropriate for your specific case, you are the programmer, take charge.  See  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator is overloaded in SQL Server.  If any argument is numeric, then it defaults to a numeric plus, rather than string concatenation.

The solution is to convert the values to strings before hand.  Something like:

```
cast(@PageNumber as varchar(255))
```

Note that when using `cast()` or `convert()`, you should always include a length for the type.