# SQL Server 2012: How to display the @Var result inside a Case statement with literals before and after the @Var

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, case

SQL Server 2012: how to display the `@Var` result inside a `Case` statement with literals before and after the `@Var`?

A simple query:

```
Declare @Var1 ...    
Declare @Var2....     

Select ....    
  CASE
     WHEN ...........    
      THEN 'Display this sentence ' + @Var1 +'followed by there words'    
      ELSE 'Display these other words  '  +@Var2  'followed by these other words'    
  END
```

The error message is

> 'Display this sentence' is not a declared variable.

I know it isn't! It should be a literal statement, only with the `@Var1` result inside the literal statement.

What am I missing?

Comment: please post the actual code.  It's hard to find the syntax error in a statement when you're given pseudo-code to debug

Comment: In SQL Server, `CASE` is **not** a statement - it's an **expression** and as such, it can return one of several possible values  - but it cannot be used to control program flow. You'll need to rethink your code to take this into account - `CASE` can only **return** a value - you need to deal with displaying it outside of the `CASE`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong the way you do the concatenation, i think the error is in the logic, do you have `IF ELSE` condition ? , maybe the error you encountered is on the two variables `@var1` or `@var2` , the reason why **Display this sentence is not a declared variable** is because that is the part of concatenation with the variables.

Tips:

- Make sure that the declared variables `@var1` and `@var2` are inside the `BEGIN and END` of the condition, meaning the program reads your declaration before the `CASE WHEN` logic is being read.
- If you are not sure with the logic, just declare your 2 variables at the top of the script to make sure that it is being read/declared.

Comment: I misspoke on the error message (did it from memory on another PC).  

Here is the actual error message:



Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''Display these other words  ' to data type int.  

So,  the error message is that it thinks the text (to display) is a data type that needs to be converted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment:

> I misspoke on the error message (did it from memory on another PC). Here is the actual error message: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''Display these other words ' to data type int. So, the error message is that it thinks the text (to display) is a data type that needs to be converted. Any ideas?

Your issue (which could have been much easier to figure out, had the actual code and error been posted)

> Declare @Var1 ...

Is actually `Declare @var1 int`.

so your statement:

```
'Display this sentence ' + @Var1 +'followed by there words '
```

is failing for:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''Display these other words ' to data type int.

You simply need to convert/cast `@Var1` to `varchar` for that part of your case statement.

```
WHEN 'Display this sentence ' + convert(varchar(14), @Var1) +'followed by there words '
```

The reason you're seeing this behavior (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951365/2312877) is:

> You need to explicitly convert your parameters to VARCHAR before trying to concatenate them. When SQL Server sees @my_int (@Var1 in your case) + 'X' it thinks you're trying to add the number "X" to @my_int (@Var1) and it can't do that.

Another option is [concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx).

```
WHEN concat('Display this sentence ', @Var1, ' followed by there words ')
```