# How to display the @Var result inside a Case statement with literals before and after the @Var VERSION 2

Tags: sql-server, variables, sql-server-2012, case

Here is my Query:

```
 DECLARE @RecordCount as INT
 DECLARE @today as VARCHAR(10)

 SET @today = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
  Set @RecordCount = (Select COUNT(*)
 FROM tableABC

 select case when @RecordCount = 0
  THEN 'There was no data found for tableABC: ' + @Today 
  ELSE 'tableABC imported ' + @RecordCount +' rows for date range ' + @Today
  END
```

Error Message

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'tableABC imported'  to data type int.

Why do I get this error???

Comment: The error message contains everything what you need to solve the problem.

Comment: @recordCount is an int - you'll need to cast it

Comment: You are trying to concatenate a `VARCHAR` string ('tableABC imported') with an integer (`Select COUNT(*) from table ABC`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2012: How to display the @Var result inside a Case statement with literals before and after the @Var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813024/sql-server-2012-how-to-display-the-var-result-inside-a-case-statement-with-lit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server try to convert string to int because of [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx):

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
> rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
> lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
> precedence. **If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion,
> an error is returned**.

`INT` is 16 on list of precedece and string constant(`VARCHAR`) is lower. So SQL Server try casting every string to `INT`.

Cast `RecordCount` to string:

**[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369225)**

```
select 
   case when @RecordCount = 0
     THEN 'There was no data found for tableABC: ' + @Today 
     ELSE 'tableABC imported ' + CAST(@RecordCount AS NVARCHAR(100)) +' rows for date range ' + @Today
   end
```

also you should consider using **[`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)** for string concatenation instead of `+`. Then you don't need to cast:

```
select 
   case when @RecordCount = 0
     THEN CONCAT('There was no data found for tableABC: ',@Today)
     ELSE CONCAT('tableABC imported ', @RecordCount,' rows for date range ', @Today)
   end
```

Another solution is to use **[`FORMATMESSAGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186788.aspx)**:

```
DECLARE @RecordCount as INT = 1;
DECLARE @today as VARCHAR(10) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120);

SELECT
  CASE 
   WHEN @RecordCount = 0 THEN FORMATMESSAGE('There was no data found for tableABC: %i', @RecordCount)
   ELSE FORMATMESSAGE('tableABC imported %i rows for date range %s', @RecordCount, @today)
  END
```

Comment: @RickyTW See my updated answer for CONCAT/FORMATMESSAGE

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when @RecordCount = 0
  THEN 'There was no data found for tableABC: ' + @Today 
  ELSE 'tableABC imported ' + cast(@RecordCount as varchar(10)) +' rows for date range ' + @Today
  END
```

The problem is that when you combine things in a string, all of the elements of that string need to be a text based not numeric datatype. Since you use @RecordCount as an integer earlier, the best best is to cast it to varchar in the else statement.  There is implicit conversion between varchar and int but SQL server, for reasons that surpass my understanding, has chosen to always try to convert the text to an int rather than the other way around. Therefore the tex can;t convert and so you get the error message.

Comment: `" There is implicit conversion between varchar and int but SQL server, for reasons that surpass my understanding"` there is simple solution :)
[Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

Comment: I know the precedences, what I don't understand is the reasoning behind the precendences

Comment: This is rather clear for most broad to most narrow ones.

Comment: BUt since it makes much more sense for varchar to take precedence over int, I still don't get it. ((most of time when you need this implicit conversion it needs to convert ints to varchars not the other way.) The way they did it guarantees more errors not fewer.

Comment: It is the same logic like `every square is rectangle, but not every rectangle is square`. SQL Server always can cast INT to varchar but not vice versa