# Trying to create a date field to union two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm trying to pull together two databases in a view that will show invoicing from both systems.

One table lists invoices by date (ie January's sales are any invoice with a January date), the other table lists invoices by year and period (so, January's sales are '2017' period '7' - irrespective of date). As the second system allows invoices to be posted within a period that is from outside that periods date range, I'm trying to create a date field from the year/period fields using a case statement in order to show the same Invoiced sales as the system does.

```
LedgerYear +
case
when LedgerPeriod = 4 then '-10-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 5 then '-11-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 6 then '-12-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 7 then '-01-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 8 then '-02-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 9 then '-03-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 10 then '-04-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 11 then '-05-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 12 then '-06-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 1 then '-07-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 2 then '-08-01'
when LedgerPeriod = 3 then '-09-01'
end
as 'InvDate',
```

I'm getting the following..

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Presumably, the LedgerYear is numeric and the '-10-01' etc are varchars. The InvDate in the other table in the union is in 'datetime' format.

How can I get the output of the case statement to be in datetime format?

Comment: Sample data and desired results are really helpful in explaining a problem.

Comment: try this select CAST(CAST(ledgeryear as float) as int)

Comment: which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Concatenate Numbers and Strings to Format Numbers in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951320/how-to-concatenate-numbers-and-strings-to-format-numbers-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need a `cast`:

```
select (cast(LedgerYear as varchar(255)) +
        case . . .
       ) as InvDate
```

Notes:

- The `+` operator works on both strings and numbers.  When any argument is a number, it is addition.  Hence the need for a `cast()`/`convert()`.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column names.
- In SQL Server, you can add this as a computed column so you only have to do the calculation once:

  alter table t add invDate as (cast(Ledgeryear as varchar(255)) + case . . . );

Then, the column is available in the table.

Comment: That fixed it - Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to cast or convert it back to date format after joining the values

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers suggesting a `CAST` or `CONVERT`, you can also concatenate string and numeric type values with the [`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh231515.aspx) function, which will implicitly convert any non-string type arguments as required (where an implicit conversion is possible):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( LedgerYear, 
            CASE LedgerPeriod
                WHEN 1 THEN '-07-01'
                WHEN 2 THEN '-08-01'
                WHEN 3 THEN '-09-01'
                WHEN 4 THEN '-10-01'
                WHEN 5 THEN '-11-01'
                WHEN 6 THEN '-12-01'
                WHEN 7 THEN '-01-01'
                WHEN 8 THEN '-02-01'
                WHEN 9 THEN '-03-01'
                WHEN 10 THEN '-04-01'
                WHEN 11 THEN '-05-01'
                WHEN 12 THEN '-06-01'
            END
          ) AS InvDate,
FROM someTable
```

*I switched up your `CASE` statement from a `searched CASE` to `simple CASE` statement to remove some repetition, you could equally use `CHOOSE` for further simplification as per [Prdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/prdp)'s answer:*

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( LedgerYear, 
            CHOOSE( @LedgerPeriod, '-07-01',
                                   '-08-01',
                                   '-09-01',
                                   '-10-01',
                                   '-11-01',
                                   '-12-01',
                                   '-01-01',
                                   '-02-01',
                                   '-03-01',
                                   '-04-01',
                                   '-05-01',
                                   '-06-01')
          ) AS InvDate,
FROM someTable
```

However, you can probably achieve what you're trying to do much more easily:

```
SELECT
CAST(
    CAST(@LedgerYear AS VARCHAR(4)) +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(CASE WHEN @LedgerPeriod <= 6 
                          THEN @LedgerPeriod + 6 
                          ELSE (@LedgerPeriod + 6) % 12 
                      END AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
    '01' 
AS DATETIME) AS columnName
FROM someTable
```

*(and there's probably an even more elegant way to shift your period numbers to month numbers)*

This gives you an actual `DATETIME` field, which you can choose to present any way you like using [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_3) or [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
DECLARE @LedgerYear INT = 2016
DECLARE @LedgerPeriod INT = 4
DECLARE @LedgerDate DATETIME

SELECT @LedgerDate =
    CAST(
        CAST(@LedgerYear AS VARCHAR(4)) +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(CASE WHEN @LedgerPeriod <= 6 
                              THEN @LedgerPeriod + 6 
                              ELSE (@LedgerPeriod + 6) % 12 
                          END AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
        '01' 
    AS DATETIME) 

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@LedgerDate,101) -- U.S. (slashes)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@LedgerDate,110) -- USA (hyphens)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@LedgerDate,103) -- British/French (slashes)

SELECT FORMAT(@LedgerDate, 'd', 'en-US') -- US English
SELECT FORMAT(@LedgerDate, 'D', 'en-US') -- US English verbose
SELECT FORMAT(@LedgerDate, 'd', 'en-GB') -- British English
SELECT FORMAT(@LedgerDate, 'D', 'en-GB') -- British English verbose

SELECT FORMAT(@LedgerDate, 'dd_|_MM_|_yyyy') -- Custom format
```

Remember that according to MSDN:

> FORMAT relies on the presence of .the .NET Framework Common Language Runtime (CLR).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 2012+ then you can use use `CONCAT` and `Choose` function

```
select concat(LedgerYear , choose(LedgerPeriod,'-07-01',
                                               '-08-01',
                                               '-09-01',
                                               '-10-01',
                                               '-11-01',
                                               '-12-01',
                                               '-01-01',
                                               '-02-01',
                                               '-03-01',
                                               '-04-01',
                                               '-05-01',
                                               '-06-01')) as  'InvDate'
```

`CONCAT` does implicit conversion

Comment: I've never come across `CHOOSE` before, useful to know, thanks!